# Making a bot for "Plug.dj"

Tags: java, php, web, bots

I want to create a bot for plug.dj.
All this bot would do is type something in the chat every 5 minutes.

I was wondering which language I should use.

I am pretty good at Java.

And how would I make it?
Can some one link an example?

Thank you very much. Sorry if I am asking for much, I just need to get started with this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Node.js with [PlugAPI](https://github.com/plugCubed/plugAPI) - their documentation is very good and has some examples. Pretty sure this would be the easiest way to do it, don't know of any Plug libraries in Java.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think Ill go with that! Ill mark your asnwer as the best answer as soon as possible.